# oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: 'type', 'authorized_user' or 'service_account' values should be set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to access the BigQuery API from my Python script. At the moment I'm experimenting only trying to get [this sample](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart#completecode) to run.

I've created credentials, set the environment variable and ran the script, only to get this error:

```
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: An error was encountered while reading json file: /PATH/TO/MY/google_api_credentials.json (pointed to by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable): 'type' field should be defined (and have one of the 'authorized_user' or 'service_account' values)
```

Well, it isn't set in the JSON file:

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"blahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"blahblah","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"blahblah","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

Since I downloaded the JSON from the Google console, it should just work? I do not know what 'type' I would need to define.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON file that you provided is for an OAuth client. When you using application default credentials, you need to provide a JSON service account key. Try going to [this page](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/permissions/serviceaccounts), clicking "Create service account", filling out the form, and choosing "Furnish a new private key."

Comment: Thanks. I have to say that Google's documentation on these things is sometimes a bit rubbish!